# Should SignalR be stopped and restarted after registering new client methods? Or can .start be called consecutively?

Tags: azure, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

When calling client methods from the Hub SignalR documentation says  to "Define methods the hub calls using connection.on after building, but before starting the connection":

[image]

In another section the documentation just says this is a best practice.

SO if I'm adding/removing a lot of methods for a given client/hub pair, can I just start the hub, add/remove a method with connection.On(), and call .start() again to ensure it's registered?
OR do I have to close() and then call start()?

Comment: Neither, you can add or remove methods and it'll automatically start working. It's considered bad practice because you could easily miss messages that are sent before you register the `.On` handler, but there could be some valid use cases for it.

Comment: Thanks @Brennan. 
You started with 'neither', but your answer seems to indicate you meant 'either'. 
Either solution will work the same, you think?
Meaning, it is required to call HubConnection.start() at some point, right?

Comment: Well you have to call start to connect to the endpoint. But after that you don't need to do anything. In fact calling start again without stopping will likely throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods can be removed/added after starting without requiring a restart.